# How can I create Firebase dynamic links using createDynamicLink()?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to get a dynamic shortened **URL** like the ones offered by services such as [**bitly**](https://bitly.com/). But I keep getting an error from the following code snippet that is executing the desired implementation:-

```
       FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("http://testtt.com/"))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("mytest.page.link")
            .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder().build())
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                        String s = shortLink.toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        // Error
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "getDynamicLink:onFailure", e);
                }
            });
```

Every time the `onFailure` method is executed indicating an exception has resulted and the error message below is produced

```
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 8: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzde.zza(Unknown Source:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzemf.zza(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzemk.onTransact(Unknown Source:29)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:681)
```

Can someone give me some tips on how to solve this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to double-check that you've created the URL path prefix (that is, "mytest.page.link") in the Firebase console first before generating short-links programmatically.